# Reorder ids to be sequential

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I have ids separated like 2,3,12,22,23,24, because of adding and deleting items.
So I want to reorder them starting in 1 and set each item sequentially then set auto_increment to the last of them + 1.

I've read similar questions, but no one said why they want this, well I need this because if the ids reach the limit number (255) I won't be able to add more items in the table, and it's ridiculous because there will be like just 30 items in it.

This is probably either easy or I'm missing something, please help me.

Comment: Question: Why can't you go over the limit of 255? If you set the field to an INT, you'll get a max of 2,147,483,647. BIGINT will give you even more

Comment: Woah that's a quick answer, thank you so much!
I knew I was missing something haha

Comment: Oh it doesn't work, keeps saying 255 it's the limit, in both int and bigint, I just tried adding a new item when the auto_increment was 256 and my table disappeared :/

Comment: Well, that's strange. There could be something in your code preventing anything from ID 255 onwards. - whilst I can't answer your question perfectly, I can give you a workaround (I'll post as an answer)

Comment: I just realized the width is in bytes? because I tried with 11 instead of 255 and I can add more than 11 items in the table.
This new table had 15 items and no problems like the old one that dissapeared for no reason.
I think this is solved. thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, here's my workaround for your situation (forgive the ugly hacky way to return array key 0.
This is also assuming you're using MySQLi and have already connected to the database

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `t1`.`id` + 1 FROM `grpgusers` AS `t1` WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `grpgusers` AS `t2` WHERE `t2`.`id` = `t1`.`id` + 1) LIMIT 1");
$getID = mysqli_data_seek($query, 0);
$temp = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$id = $temp[0];
```

Then, on your insert query, add in the new $id.
For example:
`mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO`items`(`name`,`etc.`) VALUES ('{escaped postdata}', 'etc.')");`
Should then be changed to:
`mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO`items`(`id`,`name`,`etc.`) VALUES (".$id.", '{escaped postdata}', 'etc.')");`